# JQuery: find an element in a dynamically generated HTML snippet

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var snippet = $('<div><span class="findme">text</span></div><div class="findme2"></div>');

alert(snippet.find('.findme2').length);
```

The alert shows 0.

How can I find the findme2 div through JQuery? Assume that I cannot modify the structure of the above HTML snippet (for example: adding DIV to wrap the snippet)

**Update**

I have to use Jquery 1.11.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** otherwise it search inside the elements

```js
var snippet = $('<div><span class="findme">text</span></div><div class="findme2"></div>');

alert(snippet.filter('.findme2').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or wrap with an element and then use **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```js
var snippet = $('<div><span class="findme">text</span></div><div class="findme2"></div>');

alert($('<div>', {
  html: snippet
}).find('.findme2').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pranav, I copied your code. It is working. Let me check more careful.

Comment: Pranav, sorry for that. Thanks so much for helping me!!

Comment: @curious1 : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

compatible with Jquery 1.11.x.

```
var snippet = $('<div><span class="findme">text</span></div>').append('<div class="findme2"></div>');

alert(snippet.find('.findme2').length);
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m85rm9qt/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` instead of `find()`

```
var snippet = $('<div><span class="findme">text</span></div><div class="findme2"></div>');

alert(snippet.filter('.findme2').length);
```

> NOTE:  filter will select subset of element from the selected element
>   find will select descendent of selected element